# How do you get the dialogs in td (telegram)

Tags: go, telegram

I am using gotd/td api for telegram. I want to make a request to get all the users from dialogs (i.e. chats when there is only me and another person, ignoring the group chats etc). I'm using the messagesGetDialogsRequest, but when i ask for all the users from dialogs it return the users from group chats as well, which i don't need. Is there a method that i could use for my goal?